# Asp.Net Web API, Unity container, what happens to the object between sessions?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Sorry for the title, feel free to update it if you have a better one.

Basically, I am writing a web api using ASP.Net Web API. I have configured a Unity container like this:

```
string xmlFilePath = "some/path"

var unity = new UnityContainer();
unity.RegisterType<PlayerController>();
unity.RegisterType<IRepository, XmlRepository>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(xmlFilePath));
config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
```

XmlRepository has some objects in it that represent the state of the xml file, and a timer that will write the state to an xml file every 60 seconds. This is to avoid having to rewrite the xml file every time the state changes, while limiting the maximum amount of state changes that can be lost to 60 seconds.

My question is this.. The unity container creates a singleton of XmlRepository that is available to my web api throughout every call. However, what happens to the object between calls? Is it in some serialized form somewhere, or does it stay in it's original form so my timer will continue to function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton objects stay in memory. In your case it will be managed by the Unity container. It will not be serialized and if you have started some timers on it they will continue to work ... until IIS decides to recycle your AppDomain. Now go and read [*The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET*](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: That's all I needed to know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, that's not all you needed to know. I was still updating my when you typed your comment answer. Now take a look at my answer. The last sentence is very important.